# change wireless interface name based on USB point

Tags: usb, interface

I have a wireless USB dongle connected to my computer, but which my system always labels as wlan1. What I would really like to do is rename the interface based on which slot ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 it is plugged into. Is this possible on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that I could achieve a similar thing by editing

```
nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

I had the following two lines:

```
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="80:1f:02:a1:ae:3c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="80:1f:02:a1:ae:4d", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```

I have two USB ports. I have only one dongle. I found that by plugging in the dongle to the 1st port, it was named wlan0, and to the second port wlan1. For the lines above it looks like the same physical hardware was assigned a different MAC address depending on which USB port it was plugged into. I chose my own ordering by changing the lines to read the following way:

```
# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="80:1f:02:a1:ae:3c", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

# USB device 0x:0x (rtl8192cu)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="80:1f:02:a1:ae:4d", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
```